# Should backbone receive escaped JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django-REST and I have my APIView which makes a server response like:

```
return Response(r.200_OK, JSONRenderer().render(my_dict))
```

In Chrome, I can see that the response is:

"{\"cart_product\":1,\"pk\":\"35\"}"

Is this a format which Backbone expects on a model.save() for instance? Should it be escaped like that?

The reason I ask, is because the next time I do model.save() on the same model, the request payload looks like:

```
{"cart_product":2, "{\"cart_product\":2,\"pk\":\"36\"}":{"validate":true,"parse":true,"emulateHTTP":false,"emulateJSON":false,"xhr":{"readyState":4,"responseText":"\"{\\\"cart_product\\\":2,\\\"pk\\\":\\\"36\\\"}\"","status":201,"statusText":"CREATED"}}}
```

which looks really messed up to me.

Comment: No, it should not be escaped. Looks like your controller is returning a string, not an object. Perhaps check that `my_dict` is actually a dictionary and not already converted to json.

Comment: Thanks. This cleared things up for me. Looks like I'm rendering my objects to Json multiple times. Please add your comment as an answer, and I'd be happy to mark it as answered!

Comment: I'm surprised that this is rendering properly for you (not throwing an error), but you are actually double-rendering the data. `Response` will automatically render it for you.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yup, that's right. Response() takes care of it!